# How to take a hash of a line in CSV and add it as a last column

Tags: linux, bash, csv, hash, awk

I have a file:

```
cat test.csv
Unix,10,A
Linux,30,B
Solaris,40,C
Fedora,20,D
Ubuntu,50,E
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
Unix,10,A,f9be1a25bec3e55418e4f6a75a6bdceecb6d6d17af911d8b4ef478431edc68d2
Linux,30,B,659c957414b20e098c299a5769f0c05b225b7fef007cd0e71e0355f7bc8afe5c
Solaris,40,C,3189a15aa81b86277e8e910eeb17a2d6a4e52fbdcbf326034d7691471788b9b7
Fedora,20,D,14a0ae4fb2a3bd2209f60969d75bee5ca243921f02be8ffc0f37f2ea9354f0b2
Ubuntu,50,E,dc635842ca6f904ca658ec71b5d9205221664688eaa028917663ab9760e823c3
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
while read line; 
do
  echo -n $line | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "SECRET" | cut -d' ' -f2
done < test.csv
```

And it gives me the desired hash, but I don't know how to add hashes at the end. I was looking at tool called `awk` but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read -r line
do
  echo "$line","$(echo -n $line | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "SECRET" | cut -d' ' -f2)"
done < test.csv
```

This produces the output:

```
Unix,10,A,f9be1a25bec3e55418e4f6a75a6bdceecb6d6d17af911d8b4ef478431edc68d2
Linux,30,B,659c957414b20e098c299a5769f0c05b225b7fef007cd0e71e0355f7bc8afe5c
Solaris,40,C,3189a15aa81b86277e8e910eeb17a2d6a4e52fbdcbf326034d7691471788b9b7
Fedora,20,D,14a0ae4fb2a3bd2209f60969d75bee5ca243921f02be8ffc0f37f2ea9354f0b2
Ubuntu,50,E,dc635842ca6f904ca658ec71b5d9205221664688eaa028917663ab9760e823c3
```

Comment: +1 I *was* going to ask you to escape your quotes around SECRET - but I tested it and learned something new today!

Answer (score 2):

`paste` is a handy tool for joining lines: first print the line as-is, then print the hash, then join the lines with a comma:

```
while read line; do
  echo "$line"
  echo -n "$line" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "SECRET" | cut -d' ' -f2
done < test.csv | 
paste -d, - -
```

```
Unix,10,A,f9be1a25bec3e55418e4f6a75a6bdceecb6d6d17af911d8b4ef478431edc68d2
Linux,30,B,659c957414b20e098c299a5769f0c05b225b7fef007cd0e71e0355f7bc8afe5c
Solaris,40,C,3189a15aa81b86277e8e910eeb17a2d6a4e52fbdcbf326034d7691471788b9b7
Fedora,20,D,14a0ae4fb2a3bd2209f60969d75bee5ca243921f02be8ffc0f37f2ea9354f0b2
Ubuntu,50,E,dc635842ca6f904ca658ec71b5d9205221664688eaa028917663ab9760e823c3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk`.  Not sure why it give different `hash`, but it should work:

```
awk '{cmd="echo -n \""$0"\" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac \"SECRET\"";cmd | getline var;close(cmd);sub(/.* /,"",var);print $0 "," var}' file
Unix,10,A,f9be1a25bec3e55418e4f6a75a6bdceecb6d6d17af911d8b4ef478431edc68d2
Linux,30,B,659c957414b20e098c299a5769f0c05b225b7fef007cd0e71e0355f7bc8afe5c
Solaris,40,C,3189a15aa81b86277e8e910eeb17a2d6a4e52fbdcbf326034d7691471788b9b7
Fedora,20,D,14a0ae4fb2a3bd2209f60969d75bee5ca243921f02be8ffc0f37f2ea9354f0b2
Ubuntu,50,E,dc635842ca6f904ca658ec71b5d9205221664688eaa028917663ab9760e823c3
```

---

Or written like this:

```
awk '{
    cmd="echo -n \""$0"\" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac \"SECRET\""
    cmd | getline var
    close(cmd)
    sub(/.* /,"",var)
    print $0 "," var}
    ' test.csv
```

Comment: `echo -n`  would remove `\n` from the end and hash would be the same as in question.

Answer (score 1):

@ glenn, why need paste?

```
while read line
do  
    echo -n "$line,"
    echo -n $line | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "SECRET" | cut -d' ' -f2
done < test.csv
```